# On the Samsung galaxy watch, do I need Spotify premium to be able to access Spotify?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-gear

I've recently bought a Samsung gear S3 Frontier and I want to listen to Spotify with it. Do I need to have a Spotify premium account as well as on my android phone to be able you access Spotify on my watch?

Comment: Dunno.  Why not try it and see, then answer your own question and tell us what you learn?